# How to programmatically select all WebView content?

Tags: android, webview, selection, clipboard

Is there a way to programmatically select **all** WebView content?

I know how to put the WebView into "text selection mode". But that relies on the **user** to do the selection, manually.

If there is a way to programmatically select *all* WebView content, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to select something in WebView programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

try `mWebview.evaluateJavascript("document.execCommand('selectAll');",null);`

Comment: worked for me, perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can iterate across all the "elements" and call `.select()` on each one of them. Nothing specific to Android though.